# Would this algorithm be considered a minimal-change algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, permutation

For my algorithms class we are required to write a bottoms-up minimal-change algorithm.

As an example output our professor provided us with

```
n=4
1234     2314     3124
1243     2341     3142
1423     2431     3412
4123     4231     4312
4132     4213     4321
1432     2413     3421
1342     2143     3241
1324     2134     3214
```

Notice that it generates 24 permutations (6 for each digit). The permutations for 4 (as in, 4 being the first number in a permutation) are a byproduct from the other calls in that algorithm. You can also see that at most only 2 numbers every switch positions.

I've been struggling to find a good pattern within those numbers to base my code on.
So I was thinking of taking a slightly different approach to the problem.

If I take the factorial of `n` I can calculate the number of permutations. By dividing the number of permutations by `n` I get the number of times each digit is in each respective position (i.e. how many permutations start with each number). Dividing the subsequent result by n-1 I get the number of times each second digit will occur, given the first digit remains the same. So on and so forth (with n being decreased by one every time) until all digits have been exhausted.

As an example, assume that `n=4`

```
4! = 24
24/4 = 6
6/3 = 2
2/2 = 1
```

Using these results I can generate permutations vertically, not horizontally.

Instead taking a number and sliding it back and forth over the other numbers and doing swaps every so often I would instead generate a table that is `nxn!` in dimension. Then, going down the columns fill in the first column with 6 ones, 6 twos, 6 threes, 6 fours, and 6 fives.

When I get to second column each number would be put in twp times, and then repeated until the end of the array is reached. Subsequently, each column would follow a similar pattern. This pattern would work with any sized `n` input.

My output would be this:

```
n=4
1234    2134    3124    4123
1243    2143    3142    4132
1324    2314    3214    4213
1342    2341    3241    4231
1423    2413    3421    4312
1432    2431    3412    4321
```

Now my question is... is this still considered a minimal-change algorithm?

My algorithm works more in lexicographical order, and that worries me that it may not be considered a minimal-change algorithm (because during certain steps more than one number seems 'swapped', though in reality no swapping is being done).

Comment: I encountered something like this in a [project euler](http://projecteuler.net) problem. I had to use [factoradics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system) to give a proper ordering to the permutations. With that, you could arrange them however you want.

Comment: Are you saying that I could use my technique, and reorder my output to match his?

Comment: No, it's not a minimum-change algorithm.

Comment: The only thing I can find on minimal change algorithms is the Johnson-Trotter algorithm on the [Permutations Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_with_minimal_changes). Now I know I'm not the right person to answer this question, but I'm kind of interested. Can you point me towards some more info on this type of algorithm?

Comment: It's funny that you mention it because I also had to create a Johnson-Trotter algorithm in C#. The best information I've gotten is from a a book called "Introduction to the Design and Analysis of Algoirthms" by Anany Levitin. It's a college-level textbook. If you look hard enough you can find it for real cheap (I bought an international edition for $25). And honestly some stuff in that book doesn't even seem to appear on google, so they have some real specialized stuff. Personally, I find algorithms to be tough and challenging, but a lot of fun!

Comment: @Per if you could turn your comment into an answer I'd gladly accept it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not a minimum-change algorithm—the requirement is that each adjacent pair of permutations in the output differ by one swap.